# How to create a Unique (Index) constraint across multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, index, unique-constraint

Is there a way to create a unique index across tables in a SQL Server database?
I have two tables, Table A and Table B. In that I have a Column named ID, I want to make these Id columns as unique (combining Table A and B's Ids )

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you mean that it is permitted to have same IDs on tables A and B? For example, in Table A `ID := 7` and in Table B `ID := 7` at the same time?

Comment: @vonPryz No, I dont want duplicate contents combing two tables. I mean I dont want to allow ID=7 in table B if ID=7 already exist in Table A.

Answer (score 8):

You could [use a sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) for generating the values for ID fields. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx) explicitly mentions your use case. The example C on said page has a sample implementation about this.

> Use sequences instead of identity columns in the following scenarios:
>
> - The application requires sharing a single series of numbers
>     between multiple tables or multiple columns within a table.

Be aware that there are a few catches. For example, sequence values are reusable, are not unique by default and can contain gaps. Pay attention to the Limits part in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

table c

```
tableAid pk fk table a 
tableBid pk fk table b
```

This was before the comment I dont want to allow ID=7 in table B if ID=7 already exist in Table A

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third table C, with a primary (or unique) key defined in it, and create before each row INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE triggers in both of your tables A and B that insert, update or delete their key into table C. You could use table C for foreign keys also, if you need to.